# Donate Combo Needed

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Looking for a really superb and evil combo to [DONATE](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDONATE%5d) a 'gift' to my opponent. So far I have [Glacial Chasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlacial%20Chasm%5d) and [Thought Lash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThought%20Lash%5d). I want something that is not easily gotten rid of once the 'gift' is delivered.

Playing blue control but heavy artifact. Goals are lockdown and kill his library. Thoughts and comments welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I just want to point out, as someone mentioned in an answer to your previous question, that donating Glacial Chasm doesn't accomplish anything useful. They can simply choose not to pay the cumulative upkeep as soon as they don't want it anymore. You'd be better off keeping a Glacial Chasm and paying for its upkeep to protect yourself long enough to get your combo online.

Comment: Or awaken the Glacial Chasm and stick an Assault Suit on it if you want to get janky. I think I'll try that in my pillow fort deck now that I think of it.

Comment: @Michael The assault suit doesn't force anyone to pay the cost, even with the "can't be sacrificed".

Comment: No, but it keeps the chasm around, stopping attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zedruu the Greathearted](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZedruu%20the%20Greathearted%5d) decklists are good sources of cards to use in combination with donate mechanics.

Depending on what you want to do there are a number of options, but some would require you to add an extra color to your deck.

For example to slow down and opponent's board state there are [Steel Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSteel%20Golem%5d) and [Grid Monitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrid%20Monitor%5d),
and for dealing damage there are [Rust Elemental](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRust%20Elemental%5d), [Jinxed Idol](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJinxed%20Idol%5d) and [Bronze Bombshell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBronze%20Bombshell%5d).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like Steel Goelm or Grid Monitor and Phyrexian Obliterator/Negator have possibilities. Also considering Mimic Vat/Acidic Slime.